# How to parse dynamic object in mvc?

Tags: arrays, asp.net-mvc-4, dynamic, deserialization

I am working on ASP.NET MVC4.0.

My string is posting like this from view :-

```
[{"name":"AddressNumber","value":"1"},{"name":"OrganizationProd","value":""},{"name":"ClientId","value":""},{"name":"ProductId","value":""},{"name":"TaxId1","value":""},{"name":"TaxId2","value":""},{"name":"LaborID","value":"0"}]
```

And below is my controller's action method for that,which is receiving the input :-

```
[AllowAnonymous]
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult UpdateProducts(string ModelString){
}
```

And below is the string which i am getting in action(in ModelString variable):-

```
[{"name":"AddressNumber","value":"1"},{"name":"OrganizationProd","value":""},{"name":"ClientId","value":""},{"name":"ProductId","value":""},{"name":"TaxId1","value":""},{"name":"TaxId2","value":""},{"name":"LaborID","value":"0"}]
```

And after that i am deserializing the string like that :-

```
var sear = new JavaScriptSerializer();
var dictDynamic = sear.Deserialize<dynamic>(ModelString);
```

And i am getting the dynamic array in dictDynamic variable.And now i want to get the properties by its name not by indexing from dictDynamic object.

Currently i am getting the properties by indexing like this :-

```
dictDynamic[0]["value"] 
dictDynamic[1]["value"]
```

But i want to parse it by properties name like this :-

```
dictDynamic["Name"]["value"] 
dictDynamic["Description"]["value"]
```

Can anyone help me out on this ?

Answer (score 2):

You could use ViewModel on server side, not sending model string.

You create ViewModel like this:

```
class ProductViewModel {

   public int AddressNumber { get; set; }
   public int ProductId { get; set; }
     ...
}
```

Then change your controller method:

```
[AllowAnonymous]
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult UpdateProducts(ProductViewModel vm){
  ...
}
```

And from your View you'll send json object like this:

```
{
   "AddressNumber":"10",
   "OrganizationProd":"1",
   "ClientId":"1",
   "ProductId":"1",
   "TaxId1":"23",
   "TaxId2":"23",
   "LaborID":"10"
}
```

This will automaticaly bind your values from View to ViewModel on controller, and you can than use ViewModel object in your code, and you then have strongly typed entity.

Instead of this:

```
dictDynamic["AddressNumber"]
dictDynamic["OrganizationProd"]
```

now you can write this:

```
vm.AddressNumber
vm.OrganizationProd
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass a JavaScript **object** to your function instead of an array. Array is not the correct data structure to use in this case. Objects have keys and values. The keys will be AddressNumber, OrganizationProd, ClientId, ProductId, TaxId1 etc. Their values will be 1, "", "0" etc.

For instance, for your example, this will be your object:

```
{
   "AddressNumber":1,
   "OrganizationProd":"",
   "ClientId":"",
   "ProductId":"",
   "TaxId1":"",
   "TaxId2":"",
   "LaborID":0
}
```

You deserialize it like you do now:

```
var s = "{\"AddressNumber\":1, \"OrganizationProd\":\"\", \"ClientId\":\"\", \"ProductId\":\"\", \"TaxId1\":\"\", \"TaxId2\":\"\", \"LaborID\":0}";
var sear = new JavaScriptSerializer();
var dictDynamic = sear.Deserialize<dynamic>(s);
```

Once you deserialize, you will be able to reference the values like this:

```
dictDynamic["AddressNumber"]
dictDynamic["OrganizationProd"]
```

Comment: Not working.It is giving error "string can not converted into int"

Comment: I have very little information about how you construct the JSON that you pass to your action method, so it's hard for me to help you about this issue. I'm updating the answer to include a sample JSON string.